# recursively scan all the directories under the root directory and find only the newest file from each folder

Tags: c#

that's what i try but it return only the newest file from only the top directories under the root

```
if(Directory.Exists("YourPath"))
foreach (string _tempFiles in Directory.GetDirectories("YourPath")
                       .Select(directory => Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       .OrderByDescending(File.GetLastWriteTime)
                       .FirstOrDefault()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns all newest files of each directory(including root):

```
var rootDirFile = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(yourPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .OrderByDescending(f => File.GetLastWriteTime(f))
    .Take(1);
var allNewestFilesOfEachFolder = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(yourParth, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(d => Directory.EnumerateFiles(d, "*.*")
        .OrderByDescending(f => File.GetLastWriteTime(f))
        .FirstOrDefault());
// put both together, the root-file first
allNewestFilesOfEachFolder = rootDirFile.Concat(allNewestFilesOfEachFolder);
```

If there's no file in a directory the file is `null`, so the number of files is equal to the number of folders.

Note that Linq is not the right tool for `System.IO` since error-handling is difficult.

Comment: this is missing files, if for example i have root folder with 10 folder inside, and files inside the root folder (not inside the 10 folders) it return only the newest file from each folder but not the file from the root folder

Comment: @user1269592: Edited my answer to include the root.

Comment: hoe can i Cobain this 2 together in order to put it inside foreach statement ?

Comment: @user1269592: i've put them already together with `Concat`. Have a look at the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a basic recursive function to handle this:

```
// Dictionary: 
//   Key = The directory name.
//   Value = The most recently modified file for that directory.
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetNewestFiles(string directory)
{
  return GetNewestFiles(directory, null);
}

static Dictionary<string, string> GetNewestFiles(string directory, 
                                                 Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
  if(dictionary == null)
    dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  try
  {
    var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(directory)
                select new FileInfo(file);

    var latestFile = files.OrderByDescending(file => { return file.LastWriteTimeUtc; }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (latestFile != null)
      dictionary[latestFile.DirectoryName] = latestFile.FullName;
  }
  catch { }

  foreach (var subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
  {
    try
    {
      GetNewestFiles(subDirectory, dictionary);
    }
    catch { }
  }

  return dictionary;
}
```

So then you can just call it like so:

`var fileDictionary = GetNewestFiles(@"C:\MyFolder");`